# Issue with Ranking / Row Number / Ordering

Tags: row, teradata, rank, partition

I'm trying to apply a certain type of ranking system to my data-set and having trouble.

My Issue:

```
RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Staff, Storage ORDER BY Order_Flow)
```

Essentially, whenever Storage 20 occurs, I want to assign a number to that row, and anything between it and the next occurrence of Storage 20 has the same number. Then from the next occurrence of Storage 20 to the next, the same thing.

My current Rank function will not accurately capture Storage 80 because it only started occurring later in the order flow.

Please view image (it can start from 1, doesn't necessarily have to start from 0).

[image of example data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8jfO.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this can be solved using a `RESET WHEN` in your window function:

```
MAX() OVER(
  PARTITION BY <...> 
  ORDER BY Order_Flow 
  RESET WHEN Storage = 20
)
```

I believe you can leave out the `PARTITION BY` if you just want to control the ordering and don't need to do any partitioning.  Or just use a constant value, like `PARTITION BY 1` or something to that effect.

**Documentation:**
https://docs.teradata.com/reader/756LNiPSFdY~4JcCCcR5Cw/8uRgqNTevlcmjBfsU3WQsw

**Stackoverflow**:
[teradata, reset when, partition by, order by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53344536/teradata-reset-when-partition-by-order-by)

Comment: However, this gave an incremental and then reset. I need everything between the Storage 20s to be the same number

Comment: Ah...ok, then you can probably use a `MAX()` or `MIN()` instead of `ROW_NUMBER()`.  Sorry I don't have access to a TD system and can't view your attached images.  Can you give that a try?

Comment: Can it be any number assigned to the rows between the 20s?  Or do those numbers have to be sequential?  i.e. 10 rows between the first pair of 20s gets assigned a value of 1; the 15 rows between the next pair of 20s gets a value of 2?

Comment: Thanks Ravioli. Min() looks like it did the trick albeit assigning odd numbers. 
Sequential would be fantastic, as I imagine it would get trickier to manage in the tables that follow.

Comment: I have used this Min() method in conjunction with a second Dense_Rank to get the sequential numbers.
May not be pretty, so optimisation suggestions are definitely welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple Cumulative Sum over a CASE:

```
sum(case when Storage = 20 then 1 else 0 end)
over(Partition By Staff
     Order By Order_Flow
     rows unbounded preceding)
```

Comment: Thanks Dnoeth, this method ended up giving all records a "2". I have used the previously mentioned Min() and then did a second Dense_Rank to get the sequential numbers I was after.
If there is a more efficient way, I'd love to hear.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING`