# SQL Count reset when binary column equals 0

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a sample table below.  Im trying to create a count that resets when the `Flag` is equal to 0 without a recursive table.

```
Animal  Order  Flag
Cat     1      0
Cat     2      0
Cat     3      1
cat     4      1
cat     5      0
cat     6      1
cat     7      1
Dog     1      0
Dog     2      1
Dog     3      1
Dog     4      1
Dog     5      0
Dog     6      0
Dog     7      1
```

I have tried various `row_number` , `rank` , `dense_rank` but nothing to get me close.  The closest I got was using a lag method below but it can only count to 2 and needs to be able to count indefinitely.

Lag:
`MAX(flag )
       OVER(PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY Order
            ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)`

Desired Output

```
Animal  Order  Flag  Count
Cat     1      0     0
Cat     2      0     0
Cat     3      1     1
cat     4      1     2
cat     5      0     0
cat     6      1     1
cat     7      1     2
Dog     1      0     0
Dog     2      1     1
Dog     3      1     2
Dog     4      1     3
Dog     5      0     0
Dog     6      0     0
Dog     7      1     1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign a `grouping` to each row.  Then use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when flag = 0 then 0
             else row_number() over (partition by animal, grouping order by order) - 1
        end) as count
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when flag = 0 then 1 else 0 end) over
                 (partition by animal
                  order by order
                  rows between unbounded preceding and current row
                 ) as grouping
      from t
     ) t
```

The `- 1` is because the each sequence of `1` also includes the previous `0`.  You can also express this as:

```
             else row_number() over (partition by animal, grouping, flag order by order)
```

so only the `1`s are in the group.

Comment: This did work however I had to change the `row_number() over (partition by animal, grouping order by order)` to the following `row_number() over (partition by animal, grouping order by order) - 1`.  This was giving me the appropriate numbers as it seemed to be over counting.

Comment: @AlmostThere . . . I updated the answer to explain why and offer an alternative method.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this using `RESET WHEN`, which is a Teradata extension:

```sql
SELECT animal, order, flag,
  SUM(flag) OVER(
    PARTITION BY animal -- Group by animals
    ORDER BY order
    RESET WHEN flag = 0 -- Reset count to 0
    ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING -- Cumulative count
  ) AS count 
FROM mytable
```

I don't have a TD system to test, but give it a try and let me know.

[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53344536/teradata-reset-when-partition-by-order-by)

Comment: I tried to get this to work but  and I read through the example you shared but it just kept giving `0` at `Order` `1` and then `2` for `Order` `2` through `7`.  Thanks for sharing this!  I wasn't aware of this extension but will keep on trying it!

Comment: Oops...I forgot to include the `ROWS` line...one sec.  I updated the query, give it another try.

Comment: thanks! I was able to get it to work but I ahd to move the `rows unbounded preceding` under the `reset when flag = 0`

Comment: Woohoo!  No problem :)  I updated my answer with your fix.