# How to implement a reset when (Teradata) using ANSI SQL only?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, teradata, ansi-sql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVmCF.png)
I need to write a query that count the number of times customers transactions exceed 250 Pounds. Adding cumulatively until the sum exceeds 250 then reset and start from the following row until it exceeds 250 and so on. This functionality can be carried out using Teradata keywords 'RESET WHEN' yet I am supposed to create a query that's only composed of ANSI SQL SYNTAX.
Can anyone help with that?

```
 SUM(sales) OVER (
            PARTITION BY region
            ORDER BY day_of_calendar
            RESET WHEN sales < /* preceding row */ SUM(sales) OVER (
                 PARTITION BY region
                 ORDER BY day_of_calendar
                 ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)
            ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
       )
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVmCF.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/lu4Jp.png   This is a sample of the input of customer
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVmCF.png)
And that's the output.
Every time the customer's total spent exceeds 250, I should be summing from 0 once again and find the day at which the customer exceeded 250 USD.

Comment: Can you provide sample data and expected result?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/53344956/2527905 But it might not work, then you need recursion. Can you show some example data and expected result? If your

Comment: I have updated the post with the input and the expected output.
The last col name of the output should be passed_250 (not to confuse you).

Comment: Ok, the only way to get your expected result is a recursive query. I don't have time to write it, but there should be some examples

Comment: Ok, thank you for your response.

Comment: Please provide sample data as a runnable statement instead of an image, that will increase your chances of someone trying to help you. 
I think this can be solved using the match_recognise clause - that does exactly this.

Answer (score 0):

Without your table definitions and just a screenshot of a very limited dataset it is hard to test my answer on your data - so I'm showing it first on the dataset supplied in the match_recognize [tutorial](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/tutorial_EG95N4HMCYSL1A0Y6J80UHNHB.html) on live SQL and then with your columns:

```
SELECT
  *
  FROM
  ticker MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
    PARTITION BY symbol
    ORDER BY tstamp
    MEASURES
      nvl(SUM(up.price),0) AS tot
    ALL ROWS PER MATCH
  PATTERN ( up* ) DEFINE
    up AS SUM(up.price) - up.price <= 100
  );
```

So on your table this would be something like

```
SELECT
  *
  FROM
  your_table MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
    PARTITION BY region
    ORDER BY day_of_calendar
    MEASURES
      nvl(SUM(up.sales),0) AS tot
    ALL ROWS PER MATCH
  PATTERN ( up* ) DEFINE
    up AS SUM(up.sales) - up.sales <= 250
  );
```